# Setup BIND to transfer the zone file for every Second Level domain for a gTLD?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, tld

Is it possible to have BIND transfer all the second level domains for a single TLD to my local machine? (I'm fully aware that this would be a massive data set)

Also, how do I track changes on a daily basis?

Comment: For some TLDs, this is possible. For example, many country-level TLDs with small numbers of second-level domains, permit this.

Answer (score 12):

Theoretically maybe, but in reality almost every properly configures their domain servers to not permit zone transfers to un-trusted sources (in this case you).

So in the practical reality, the answer is **no** this is not possible.